# Any Notepad++ plugins to automatically save document versions

Tags: version-control, plugins, notepad++

Does anyone know of any notepad++ plugin that saves a version of whatever I'm working on periodically? Ideally, it would save many versions with the automatic version number and the date in the title, and perhaps store them in a zipped archive to save space.

Does something like this exist already, or shold I attempt to write such a plugin myself?

Thanks,
Cameron

P.S. It should be freeware or (preferably) open-source.

Comment: If anyone knows of a plugin that will let you compare version of a file, please see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30896/looking-for-a-simple-editor-that-can-display-diffs-of-previously-saved-versions

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Settings > Preferences > Backup tab > Click Verbose Backup

This will time stamp a copy of your file every time you save.

---

**Update:**

[AutoSave](http://fstellari.googlepages.com/npp_plugins) allows to automatically save the currently open files based on a timer schedule (default is 1 min) and/or upon the application losing focus. The plugin offers a couple of options to save the current (or all the files), selecting only the named ones, accessible through a menu.

[Via [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5303634/autosave-adds-reassurance-to-notepad%252B%252B-editing)]

---

**Update2:** 
**BEWARE**: If the Custom Backup Directory you set to is deleted/moved, then the backups won't happen! **No error is thrown notifying you of the dead link!**

Comment: "and Tick Enable Auto-completion" - This has nothing to do with backing up files. This is a code auto-completion feature in the editor itself.

Comment: +1. Select a Google Drive local folder and your backups will sync to your Google Drive account - serving both the version control and backup functions seamlessly and free.

Answer (score 7):

You might be better off looking into something closer to "real" version control - [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/), perhaps. It doesn't require a server, and it's really easy to set up.

To automate it, you could turn on autosave in Notepad++, and set up a windows scheduled task to do an `hg commit` every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are a Windows user, so you have an option of using shadow copies, but copies are probably not generated often enough.

IntelliJ Idea and some other Java IDEs have [local history feature](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2007/06/intellij-idea-local-history-a-life-saver/).

I personally use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and [svn server](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215466058-Subversion-overview) on Dreamhost. This had additional benefit of having my files stored off-site in case of disaster.