# PHP code lost because file encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, binaryfiles

I have worked a while on a PHP class, and it seems I have lost all my code! The filesize is right (around 25kb), but all I have left is, depending on which source I open, and with which editor, a full page of spaces or a huge line of question marks in black diamonds, and I wonder if anyone has a clue how to retrieve the content, and if it's still possible.

Originally the file was UTF8 encoded but it is seen now as binary (it's what SVN tells me when I try a diff). The worst part is that I have put this file on repositories (Git AND SVN!!), but the copies there are binary too, whatever version I pick. It's like if I had never opened this file before.

I tried changing encoding in Notepad++, but so far my code is still invisible. Any idea?

The Git file is https://github.com/nabab/bbn/blob/master/src/bbn/db/languages/sqlite.php

Comment: Can you link us to the git file?

Comment: That file contains 15KB worth of zeroes. There's nothing to recover there, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you restore from a previous commit?

Comment: Yes, 15KB is normal, I mistyped earlier. The zeroes are not though...

Comment: There's only one commit on the Git side, and 3 on SVN, but they're all the same.

Comment: @Nabab and no backups? =o(

Comment: It seems that upon editing you saved in the wrong encoding by mistake. I'm sorry to say this but I can't imagine of a way to go back.

Comment: @cryptic ツ I've been messing with the repo in order to create a classic trunk/tags/branches structure 10 days ago. As a result I found 20 folders with this file in my recycle bin, USB key, laptop, server... They're just all the same. Only this file is dead. I am sooooo annoyed (and very likely stupid!) Thanks all anyway

Comment: That's why I keep multiple copies of my script and backup as much as I can. I might seem paranoid, but this is one mess I really don't like to get into. Meanwhile, see if you could try opening the file with a difference Computer or OS like Linux. Funny, but I've seen some stuff in PC scramble almost any file opened.

Comment: It seems you have recovered or write again ...https://github.com/nabab/bbn/blob/master/src/bbn/db/languages/sqlite.php  ?

Comment: @Erdinç Çorbacı: I rewrote it!!

Comment: This is why I have Notepad++ (in which I do all my coding) do a full backup of every file every time I edit it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215954/any-notepad-plugins-to-automatically-save-document-versions

Comment: Well crap. Seems you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately like the other posters mentioned, i think you may have lost your code.

To help yourself in the future though you should try getting an IDE which has local history, eclipse, sublime (with the help of a plugin) and e-text editor are a few that have this. If you use it in conjunction with source control you should hopefully be able to avoid losing work between checkins.